# UISlider thumbImage cannot exit uislider frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uislider

I am trying to create a big thumb UISlider which has the benefit of showing some details about the current progress in a timeline.

[image: While the slider moves, by user drag or following a timer, the slider displays information]

However I am having big troubles (even subclassing the UISlider) on making the thumb start from the extreme left and get to the extreme right. It seems that the thumb can't exit the frame size of the UISlider. I have tried subclassing and implementing

```
- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value
    CGRect result = [super thumbRectForBounds:bounds trackRect:rect value:value];
    result = CGRectOffset(result, -100, -125);
    return result;
}
```

This way it works, but in this example (for example with a negative x offset) the slider stops to the right at about half the track. I think the right way to implement this method would be with a dynamic x offset which depends on the value of the track.

I just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing a big hole or a straightforward way to accomplish that which doesn't involve custom image views following the sliders and so on.

Any Idea?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Supeandr, Did you found any solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `clipsToBounds:` set to no?  I remember having to do this for a project about 18 months ago, but due to the amount of customisation occurring after every round of feedback, I just wrote my own slider, using UIViews, and the UIPanGestureRecognizer; more work, but much easier to customise.

Comment: thanks, clipToBounds is set to NO (by default I guess) if I set to yes the problem persists and views are clipped this way: http://d.pr/i/9o4B